# After making changes in XML file, old data is loading in Java application

Tags: java, xml

I am making some changes to an embedded XML file in my Java application. I have some fields, a LOAD button and a SAVE button. After clicking the save button I can see the XML file updating, but after clicking the load button the old values are being loaded to the fields.

Here is my code:

```
public class MyLoad_SaveSampleProject {
    public String field1 = "";
    public String field2 = "";

    public void loadSampleProject() {
        InputStream file = MyLoad_SaveSampleProject.class.getResourceAsStream("/main/resources/otherClasses/projects/SampleProject.xml");

        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory DocBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder DocBuilder = DocBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document Doc = DocBuilder.parse(file);
            NodeList list = Doc.getElementsByTagName("*"); //create a list with the elements of the xml file

            for (int i=0; i<list.getLength(); i++) {
                Element element = (Element)list.item(i);
                if (element.getNodeName().equals("field1")) {
                    field1 = element.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue().toString();
                } else if (element.getNodeName().equals("field2")) {
                    field2 = element.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue().toString();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public void saveSampleProject(String field1Str, String field2Str) {
        InputStream file = MyLoad_SaveSampleProject.class.getResourceAsStream("/main/resources/otherClasses/projects/SampleProject.xml");
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory DocBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder DocBuilder = DocBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document Doc = DocBuilder.parse(file);
            NodeList list = Doc.getElementsByTagName("*"); //create a list with the elements of the xml file

            for (int i=0; i<list.getLength(); i++) {
                Node thisAttribute = list.item(i);
                if (thisAttribute.getNodeName().equals("field1")) {
                    thisAttribute.setTextContent(field1Str);
                } else if (thisAttribute.getNodeName().equals("field2")) {
                    thisAttribute.setTextContent(field2Str);
                }
            }
            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(Doc);
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("src/main/resources/otherClasses/projects/SampleProject.xml"));
            transformer.transform(source, result);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
            pce.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
            tfe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException sae) {
            sae.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String returnField1() {
        return field1;
    }

    public String returnField2() {
        return field2;
    }
}
```

And this is my default XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><Strings>
    <field1>string1</field1>
    <field2>string2</field2>
</Strings>
```

When the save button is pressed I am using the saveSampleProject method. When the load button is pressed I am using the loadSampleProject method and then I am getting the field values with the returnField1 and returnField2 methods.

I have no idea of what could be wrong with what I'm doing. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: After you modify the xml file, you are recompiling the project and restarting your program, right?

Comment: @vikingsteve: when I recompile and restart, the file is updated. What I am asking is how it could be updated without the need to recompile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably that calling method getResourceAsStream() leads to resource caching. Since you are using File() in save method try to get InputStream on data load using File object, and not as resource.